# Is there a way to tell if a person is on Messenger or Facebook

Tags: facebook-messenger

Is there a way to tell whether a person is on Facebook or Messenger?

Answer (score -1):

On desktop go to https://www.facebook.com/messages > click on the settings symbol (cog) in the top left corner > click "active contacts" > Ctrl + f > type in their name. If their name isn't highlighted they are ether offline or have active status disabled.